# How to ask part of a list

Tags: r, list

I would like to access all elements within models that correspond to AICv. How do I do this with the following code please? I do not want to have to write out `models[[1]]$AICv, models[[2]]$AICv` but would rather them all at the same time. Thank you

```
Model_eval_Mixed <- list(AICv=1, Probabilities = matrix(sample(9,9),3,3))
Model_eval_Tan <- list(AICv=2, Probabilities = matrix(sample(9,9),3,3))
Model_eval_Exp <- list(AICv=1.5, Probabilities = matrix(sample(9,9),3,3))
Model_eval_Gau <- list(AICv=2.5, Probabilities = matrix(sample(9,9),3,3))
#models = c(Model_eval_Tan,Model_eval_Mixed,Model_eval_Gau,Model_eval_Exp)
models = list(Model_eval_Tan=Model_eval_Tan,Model_eval_Mixed=Model_eval_Mixed,Model_eval_Exp=Model_eval_Exp,Model_eval_Gau=Model_eval_Gau)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` with function `[[` and the name `AICv`.

```
sapply(models, "[[", "AICv")
#  Model_eval_Tan Model_eval_Mixed   Model_eval_Exp   Model_eval_Gau 
#             2.0              1.0              1.5              2.5
```

Comment: Nice one mate!!

Comment: Maybe `lapply(models, "[[", "Probabilities")` ?

Answer (score 1):

`purrr::map` [family](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) of functions allows to do that if you want to leverage the tidyverse approch:

```r
library(purrr)
map_dbl(models, "AICv")
#   Model_eval_Tan Model_eval_Mixed   Model_eval_Exp   Model_eval_Gau 
#              2.0              1.0              1.5              2.5
```